# Coffeescript error in 2 lines of code

Tags: coffeescript

What's wrong with my Coffeescript? Getting "undefined is not a function, trying to evaluate..." pointing to the last row

```
jQuery ->
  $('#article_tag_list').autocomplete
    source: $('#article_tag_list').data('autocomplete-source')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`autocomplete` is not a jQuery standard thing.  Perhaps you forgot to load a jQuery plugin you are trying to use?

In fact, If I take that code, and simulate a no-op plugin called `autocomplete`, it runs without any errors.

```
jQuery.fn.autocomplete = -> # implement $().autocomplete()

jQuery ->
  $('#article_tag_list').autocomplete
    source: $('#article_tag_list').data('autocomplete-source')
```

http://jsfiddle.net/qRPL6/